# Sort dictionary alphabetically when the key is a string (name)

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

First, I know there are a LOT of posts on dictionary sorting but I couldn't find one that was exactly for my case - and I am just not understanding the sorted(...lambda) stuff - so here goes.

Using Python 3.x I have a dictionary like this:

```
dictUsers[Name] = namedTuple(age, address, email, etc...)
```

So as an example my dictionary looks like

```
[John]="29, 121 bla, some@la.com"
[Jack]="32, 122 ble, some@la.com"
[Rudy]="42, 123 blj, some@la.com"
```

And right now for printing I do the following (where response is a dictionary):

```
for keys, values in response.items():
    print("Name= " + keys)
    print ("   Age= " + values.age)
    print ("   Address= " + values.address)
    print ("   Phone Number= " + values.phone)
```

And when the user asks to print out the database of users I want it to print in alphabetical order based on the "name" which is used as the KEY.

I got everything to work - but it isn't sorted - and before starting to sort it manually I thought maybe there was a built-in way to do it ...

Thanks,

Comment: why are accepting answer that lowering the keys? you did not specify you wanted that.

Comment: this is the best answer: `sorted_dict = {key: value for key, value in sorted(unsorted_dict.items())}`

Comment: @Charlie Parker the lower() is used on keys just to sort them, in sorted() the key= parameter is to specify what to look for and compare (in this case the lowercase key) , not what to use in the return value, so it doesn't matter, the sorted dict will have same keys

Answer (score 25, accepted):

simple algorithm to sort dictonary keys in alphabetical order, First sort the keys using `sorted`

```
sortednames=sorted(dictUsers.keys(), key=lambda x:x.lower())
```

for each key name retreive the values from the dict

```
for i in sortednames:
   values=dictUsers[i]
   print("Name= " + i)
   print ("   Age= " + values.age)
   print ("   Address= " + values.address)
   print ("   Phone Number= " + values.phone)
```

Comment: This is what the debugger shows me for the "sortednames" variable created: list: ['Ahmad', 'John', 'Katya', 'a']. Clearly 'a' should be the first not last right ...

Comment: And ... I added the comma - and now I get TypeError: descriptor 'lower' of 'str' object needs an argument

Comment: @JSchwartz please try now

Comment: There is no need to say `.keys()`. And the preferred approach is `key=string.lower`, I believe, not making a new function with lambda: `>>> a = {'a': 1, 'B': 2} >>> print sorted(a)
['B', 'a']
>>> import string
>>> print sorted(a, key=string.lower)
['a', 'B']`

Comment: why are you lowering the keys? the user did not specify it wanted that.

Answer (score 38):

i would do it like:

```
sorted_dict = {key: value for key, value in sorted(unsorted_dict.items())}
```

Comment: To make it even simpler: `sorted_dict = dict(sorted(unsorted_dict.items()))`.

Answer (score 13):

```
dictio = { 'Epsilon':5, 'alpha':1, 'Gamma':3, 'beta':2, 'delta':4 }

sortedDict = dict( sorted(dictio.items(), key=lambda x: x[0].lower()) )

for k,v in sortedDict.items():
    print('{}:{}'.format(k,v))
```

output

```
 alpha:1
 beta:2
 delta:4
 Epsilon:5
 Gamma:3
```

Comment: I am not sure that you can guarantee that dict() returns keys in the right orders. It can shuffle them

Comment: why are you lowering the keys? the user did not specify it wanted that.

Answer (score 4):

```py
dict1={"d":1,"a":3,"z":0}

x=sorted(dict1.items())

print(x)
```

output

```
[('a', 3), ('d', 1), ('z', 0)]
```

Comment: what does `sorted` when taking a `dict` do?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `OrderedDict` with `sorted`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

test_dict = {}

ordered_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(test_dict.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to reiterate @hughdbrown's comment in a separate answer, because I missed it at first and believe it to be the true answer to this question:

You have a dictionary you want to sort alphabetically, say `dictio`:

`dictio = {'Beta': 2, 'alpha': 1}`

[sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) will alphabetically sort the keys for you into a list, given that you convert all keys to lowercase (otherwise uppercase entries will be sorted first, then all lowercase):

`sortedkeys = sorted(dictio, key=str.lower)`

By calling the original dictionary again using that list of sorted keys you then can output it alphabetically:

```
for i in sortedkeys:
    print dictio[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sort_dict_by_key(unsorted_dict)  

    sorted_keys = sorted(unsorted_dict.keys(), key=lambda x:x.lower())

    sorted_dict= {}
    for key in sorted_keys:
        sorted_dict.update({key: unsorted_dict[key]})

    return sorted_dict

un_sorted_dict = {'Epsilon': 5, 'alpha': 1, 'Gamma': 3, 'beta': 2, 'delta': 4}
sorted_dict = sort_dict_by_key(un_sorted_dict)
print(sorted_dict) # {'alpha': 1, 'beta': 2, 'Epsilon': 5, 'Gamma': 3, 'delta': 4}
```