# How to sort dict first by key alphabetically, then value ascending?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary, `mydict`, with the following shape:

```
{'qui': [(4, 1), (3, 2), (10, 1)], 'voluptate': [(3, 1)], 'est': [(4, 1)], 'reprehenderit': [(3, 1)], 'cillum': [(3, 1), (9, 1)], 'irure': [(1, 1), (3, 1)], 'laboris': [(2, 1)], 'sit': [(1, 1)], 'sunt': [(4, 1)], 'eu': [(3, 1)], 'nisi': [(5, 1), (2, 1)]}
```

I need to first sort the keys alphabetically, then once that is done, sort the tuples by the first number in the tuple.

I have seen resources for sorting [first by key then value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20867181/sort-dictionary-first-by-key-then-by-value), [sorting alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728933/sort-dictionary-alphabetically-when-the-key-is-a-string-name/24728952), and [sorting by value then key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742752/sorting-a-dictionary-by-value-then-by-key), but no question so far has had this issue.

I have tried using `sorted_dict = sorted(d.keys())` but that just returns a list of my keys in alphabetical order, not their values

How can I achieve a goal result like below?:

```
{'cillum': [(3, 1), (9, 1)], 'est': [(4, 1)], 'eu': [(3, 1)], 'irure': [(1, 1), (3, 1)], 'laboris': [(2, 1)], 'nisi': [(2, 1), (5, 1)], 'qui': [(3, 2), (4, 1), (10, 1)], 'reprehenderit': [(3, 1)], 'sit': [(1, 1)], 'sunt': [(4, 1)], 'voluptate': [(3, 1)],}

python --version yields Python 3.6.7
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, what is wrong with this question?

Comment: I understand sorting the values, but why does the order of the keys matter? If you are attempting to output a 
"sorted JSON", keep in mind that according to the RFC the JSON format is unordered.

Comment: I am building an info retrieval engine. This will be an inverted index, so the dictionary should first be ordered by term, and then for each term, which document it occurs in (the tuple is document_id, #_occurrences). It is a requirement for building that data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @DeepSpace OP uses Python 3.6.

For this reason dicts order is an implementation detail and we have to use OrderedDict.

Here's my version:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {'qui': [(4, 1), (3, 2), (10, 1)], 'voluptate': [(3, 1)], 'est': [(4, 1)], 'reprehenderit': [(3, 1)], 'cillum': [(3, 1), (9, 1)], 'irure': [(1, 1), (3, 1)], 'laboris': [(2, 1)], 'sit': [(1, 1)], 'sunt': [(4, 1)], 'eu': [(3, 1)], 'nisi': [(5, 1), (2, 1)]}

ordered_dict = OrderedDict()
sorted_keys = sorted(d.keys())

for key in sorted_keys:
    sorted_values = sorted(d[key])
    ordered_dict[key] = sorted_values

print(ordered_dict)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('cillum', [(3, 1), (9, 1)]), ('est', [(4, 1)]), ('eu', [(3, 1)]), ('irure', [(1, 1), (3, 1)]), ('laboris', [(2, 1)]), ('nisi', [(2, 1), (5, 1)]), ('qui', [(3, 2), (4, 1), (10, 1)]), ('reprehenderit', [(3, 1)]), ('sit', [(1, 1)]), ('sunt', [(4, 1)]), ('voluptate', [(3, 1)])])
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you'll first need to sort the inner lists (directly using `sorted` on the lists will sort the tuples based on its respective elements), and then sort the dictionary (`d` here) according to the keys and build an `OrderedDict` so that order is guaranteed in the final dictionary (order in dictionaries is guaranteed only from Python 3.7>= as @deepspace mentions):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

out = {k:sorted(v) for k,v in d.items()}
OrderedDict(sorted(out.items(), key=itemgetter(0)))

{'cillum': [(3, 1), (9, 1)],
 'est': [(4, 1)],
 'eu': [(3, 1)],
 'irure': [(1, 1), (3, 1)],
 'laboris': [(2, 1)],
 'nisi': [(2, 1), (5, 1)],
 'qui': [(3, 2), (4, 1), (10, 1)],
 'reprehenderit': [(3, 1)],
 'sit': [(1, 1)],
 'sunt': [(4, 1)],
 'voluptate': [(3, 1)]}
```

Comment: OP uses Python 3.6 where dicts order is an implementation detail so you have to use `OrderedDict`

Comment: Wait but the order is mantained from 3.6 onward right @DeepSpace ?

Comment: In Python 3.6 it's an implementation detail. In >= 3.7 it is guaranteed.

Comment: Ohh gotcha, well that is good to know thanks @DeepSpace will update

Answer (score 1):

This works, possible there's something a bit faster:

```
import Collections  # For Python < 3.7

dict_unsorted = {'qui': [(4, 1), (3, 2), (10, 1)], 'voluptate': [(3, 1)], 'est': [(4, 1)], 'reprehenderit': [(3, 1)], 'cillum': [(3, 1), (9, 1)], 'irure': [(1, 1), (3, 1)], 'laboris': [(2, 1)], 'sit': [(1, 1)], 'sunt': [(4, 1)], 'eu': [(3, 1)], 'nisi': [(5, 1), (2, 1)]}

# dict_sorted = {}  # For Python 3.7+
dict_sorted = Collections.OrderedDict()  # For Python < 3.7

for element in sorted(dict_unsorted.keys()):
  sortedVal = sorted(dict_unsorted[element])
  dict_sorted[element] = sortedVal

print(dict_sorted)
```

Comment: OP uses Python 3.6 where dicts order is an implementation detail so you have to use `OrderedDict`

Answer (score 0):

Slightly shorter one-liner:

```
d = {'qui': [(4, 1), (3, 2), (10, 1)], 'voluptate': [(3, 1)], 'est': [(4, 1)], 'reprehenderit': [(3, 1)], 'cillum': [(3, 1), (9, 1)], 'irure': [(1, 1), (3, 1)], 'laboris': [(2, 1)], 'sit': [(1, 1)], 'sunt': [(4, 1)], 'eu': [(3, 1)], 'nisi': [(5, 1), (2, 1)]}
new_d = dict(sorted([(a, sorted(b)) for a, b in d.items()]))
```

Output:

```
{'cillum': [(3, 1), (9, 1)], 'est': [(4, 1)], 'eu': [(3, 1)], 'irure': [(1, 1), (3, 1)], 'laboris': [(2, 1)], 'nisi': [(2, 1), (5, 1)], 'qui': [(3, 2), (4, 1), (10, 1)], 'reprehenderit': [(3, 1)], 'sit': [(1, 1)], 'sunt': [(4, 1)], 'voluptate': [(3, 1)]}
```

Comment: OP uses Python 3.6 where dicts order is an implementation detail so you have to use `OrderedDict`