# Sort result from dictionary read from CSV file

Tags: python, csv, sorting

I have a CSV file with many columns and rows, and I wanted to create a dictionary from one specific row (row 12 as shown in code), that have duplicates. I have managed to do this, however, I cannot figure out how to sort it. I tried sorting it before creating the dictionary, and after.
I use python through VSCode.

### This is my code:

```
import csv


with open("FILENAME", newline="", encoding="iso-8859-1") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=";")
    next(reader)
    species_count ={}
    for row in reader:
        species = row[12]
        species_count[species] = species_count.get(species,0)+1
    for num in species_count:
        print(f"{num}: {species_count[num]}")
```

Example of current result:

```
A: 5922
C: 5837
D: 6136
B: 12
E: 1
```

etc.

Is there an easy way of doing this?
Any help is appreciated! (I am a beginner)

Edit:
I want to sort it alphabetically, so:

```
A: 5922
B: 12
C: 5837
etc
```

Comment: What do you want the result to be?

Comment: I want it to be sorted alphabetically, by the first value. Probably should have specified that in my question, sorry!

Comment: `row[12]` is not row 12. It's element 12 in the current row. In other words, you're taking the elements from column 12, not from row 12.

Comment: So get the list of keys from the dictionary and sort that.

Comment: Instead of the final for-loop `for num in species_count: print(f"{num}: {species_count[num]}")`, you can write a slightly different for-loop with sorting first:`for s,c in sorted(species_count.items()): print(f'{s}: {c}')`

Comment: Also, note that there exists a subclass of `dict` called `Counter` in module `collections`, that basically implements all the counting logic so you don't have to write it yourself. You could do `from collections import Counter; species_count = Counter(row[12] for row in reader)` and boom all is taken care of in one line of code.

Comment: @Stef That worked, tried something similar earlier but could not get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: Also note that the final for-loop `for num in species_count:` does not need to be inside the `with` block. You can de-indent it so that it's outside the `with` block. The file is closed when the `with` block ends, so you can end it as soon as you have finished reading from the file.

Comment: @stef Oh ok, thanks for the info. Relatively new to programming and my first time reading CSV files so I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sorting the elements in the dict

Your code is pretty good, you just need to replace the final display loop

```py
for num in species_count:
```

with a loop on a sorted version of the content of `species_count`.

Conveniently, getting a sorted version of a collection can be done easily with builtin function `sorted`. You can sort the list of keys of the dictionary, or you can sort directly the list of pairs (key, value).

```py
# version 1
for num in sorted(species_count):
    print(f"{num}: {species_count[num]}")

# version 2
for s,c in sorted(species_count.items()):
    print(f'{s}: {c}')
```

I prefer version 2, although it's a matter of taste. They're almost (but not quite) equivalent.

### Additional comments on your code

#### Using collections.Counter

Your use of `d[k] = d.get(k,0)+1` in a loop to build a dictionary of counts works very well. However, since this is a very classic thing to do and very useful in lots of situations, there is a subclass of `dict` in python that can handle all that logic for you. The subclass is called `Counter` and is found in module `collections`. Using that class, the dictionary of counts can be built in one simple line of code:

```py
from collections import Counter

species_count = Counter(row[12] for row in reader)
```

#### Opening and closing files

The great advantage of using a `with` block like you did is that it takes care of closing the file for you. The file is closed when the `with` block ends. In my opinion, you should close the `with` block as soon as you have finished reading from the file. So, the final display loop `for num in sorted(species_count):` should be outside the `with` block.

### Final code

```py
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open("FILENAME", newline="", encoding="iso-8859-1") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=";")
    next(reader)
    species_count = Counter(row[12] for row in reader)

for s,c in sorted(species_count.items()):
    print(f'{s}: {c}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728933/sort-dictionary-alphabetically-when-the-key-is-a-string-name)

lambda function is to shorter the for loop. x is refer to the items of dictionary. Dictionary item contain key and value. Key is x at index 0 x[0] and x[1] refer to value. As we want to sort the key of dictionary.

sorted is the build-in function you can used sorted to sort the dictionary in the alphabetically order.

```
sortedDict = dict(sorted(species_count.items(), key = lambda x: x[0]))
print(sortedDict)
```

Result

```
{'A': 5922, 'B': 12, 'C': 5837, 'D': 6136, 'E': 1}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on your answer and how this solution works? Thank you!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).